# counter for availability of dedicated Azure cache

Tags: cache, azure

The following link have a list of Azure caching perf counters : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh914135.aspx#PerfCountersc2

we are interested in, to get the utilization of the cache memory on the dedicated cache worker roles. In the list there are two counters

“\Memory\Available Mbytes” - its known that this is system memory “\Azure Caching:Host\Total Available Memory Bytes” – it’s not well documented that, this is available memory for item caching or its same as system memory.

Can anyone help us out on this? Is there better counter for availability of dedicated Azure cache ?